# Java Mail Application

Tags: java, email, import, dependencies

I am just trying to create a simple Mail Application in Java.
And have found out how to code it, but I seem to have some problems with my imports.

```
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import javax.activation.*;
```

IntelliJ recommends adding Jave EE 6 JARs to module dependencies. But it just did not help! Maybe you know what to do.

Answer (score 5):

The [Answer by Mustafa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69561045/642706) seems correct but is outdated.

## *Jakarta EE*

*JavaEE* was owned by [Oracle Corporation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Corporation). JavaMail was part of JavaEE, one of the few dozen technologies housed there.

Years ago, Oracle transferred ownership to the [Eclipse Foundation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_Foundation).

- The name changed from *JavaEE* to *Jakarta EE*.
- *JavaMail* changed its name to [*Jakarta Mail*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta_Mail).
- In the latest versions, the **package names have changed** from `javax.*` to `jakarta.*`.

## *Jakarta Mail*

### Spec

Find the [Jakarta Mail specifications list](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/mail/). The current version is [Jakarta Mail 2.0](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/mail/2.0/).

### Implementation

At least one implementation exists: [*Eclipse Jakarta Mail*](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/mail/).

Others are free to write implementations as well. I do not know if anyone has or not.

### Example

I have not used Jakarta Mail myself, but your Question made me curious. So I put this dependency:

```xml
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.mail/jakarta.mail -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.mail</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

… into this Maven POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns = "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation = "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>work.basil.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>JMail</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>JMail</name>
    <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
    <url>http://www.example.com</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.mail/jakarta.mail -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.mail</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
            <plugins>
                <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.9.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.2</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

… to create a little project. I added the `Registry` class from [here](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mail/releases/download/2.0.1/jakartamail-samples.zip), a link provided [here](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/mail/#Samples).

Minor note: I fixed a typo to change the class name from `registry` to `Registry` per Java naming conventions.

Notice the imports on that file use `jakarta.*` package naming.

```java
import java.util.*;

import jakarta.mail.*;
import jakarta.mail.internet.*;
```

That `Registry` class compiles, but I did not run it.

#### Deployment

If you are writing a standalone app, you need to **include a JAR** containing an implementation. You would ship that JAR as part of your app, provided you can abide by its license.

If you are writing a web app or web service to be deployed on a Jakarta EE service, then you would change your **Maven POM to use the Jakarta Mail APIs** alone without an implementation. The implementation would be provided at runtime by the Jakarta EE compliant server product you chose for deployment.

Comment: I have never seen anyone else on this platform doing this much research for posting an answer. Certainly, this is not for mere points; it's a selfless help to developers and learners. Keep it up! God bless you!

Comment: Thank you for answering. Since I created a JavaFX project I can't add the dependency to my Maven POM. Thank you for helping me out anyway.

Comment: @TobiasJamnik You should have no problems with adding Jakarta Mail to the Maven POM of your JavaFX/OpenJFX app. If you are confused about it, or have encountered a challenge, post another Question specifically on that topic.

Answer (score 2):

> Download JavaMail Release
>
> In addition, the JavaMail jar files are published to the Maven
> repository. The main JavaMail jar file, which is all most applications
> will need, can be included using this Maven dependency:

If you use Maven,

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

> You can find all of the JavaMail jar files in both the java.net Maven
> repository, and in Maven Central.

Otherwise download the javax.mail jar and add it to your libs/classpath:

https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/releases/com/sun/mail/javax.mail/1.6.2/javax.mail-1.6.2.jar

Comment: Please post your exception if possible as an edit to the question

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering. Since I have created a Maven project I tried adding the javax.mail.jar to my libs. On the surface, it seemed to work, but on closer examination, it found out that it causes an exception, due to the javax.activation.DataHandler. If you know how to fix this please help me out. I would really appreciate it.